# Шаблонизатор Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Имеется такая структура - чистые JSP без ничего другого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это все надо перенести на Spring MVC.

Суть. в папке tpl встраиваемые части в страницы которые находятся в папке page. 
Там я их подключаю при помощи

```
<%@include file="../tpl/main-head.jsp" %>
```

Как мне такой вид перенести в Spring MVC? использовать JSTL?

Comment: Да можно и прямо так. Но лучше преобразовать в jspx и использовать JSTL.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev пример можно? пожалуйста

Comment: Пример аналогичной jspx-директивы `<jsp:directive.include file="../tpl/main-head.jspx" />`

Comment: Пример jsp-тега `<jsp:include page="tpl/main-head.jsp">`

Comment: Пример jstl-тега `<c:import url="tpl/main-head.jspx" />`

Comment: На ресурсе уже был вопрос про разницу между директивами и тегами, да и в google легко найти ответ.